# aws-cli not found on macOS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I'm on macOS 10.13 and I've a problem after installed aws-cli. I can't use aws command in my CLI.

I've installed aws-cli with *pip 18.0* used this command:

`pip install awscli --upgrade --user`

After that, aws command didn't work so I've checked the aws-cli install directory with this command:

`python -c 'import awscli; print(awscli)'`

**Output:**`/Users/XXXXX/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/awscli/__init__.pyc`

And I add it the output in my PATH directory, under the PATH for python.

`PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3:${PATH}
export PATH=$HOME/Library/Python/2.6/bin:$PATH`

Unfortunate, aws commands still doesn't works. I've checked and followed steps at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/installing.html but wasn't resolve my problem.

What's wrong with my process ? Do you have solution for me ?

Answer (score 8):

The package is named "`awscli`". The program is named "`aws`".

If executing `aws` does not launch the program, then your path is not correct.

Follow this link for Mac OSX specific instructions:

[Adding the AWS CLI Executable to your Command Line Path](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-install-macos.html#awscli-install-osx-path)

In your question, I noticed that you are mixing your PATH statement with both Python 2 and Python 3. For Python 2, you are mixing 2.6 and 2.7. I would clean that up first. Then follow the AWS instructions for installation.

Answer (score 5):

The package is named "awscli". The program is named "aws".

If executing aws does not launch the program, then your path is not correct, export aws program path by below command

```
export PATH=~/.local/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: Please add some more information on how and why this solves OPs problem. The more you elaborate your answer the more it will help other visitors with a similar question.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I make use of Python 3 alongside Anaconda.

I therefore installed the **awscli** with `conda install awscli`.

`conda list` returns:

`awscli                    1.16.133                 py36_0    conda-forge`

I also exported the aws program path and loaded the profile into the current session:

```sh
$ echo 'export PATH="~/.local/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
$ source ~/.bash_profile
```

Now `aws --version` returns:

`aws-cli/1.16.133 Python/3.6.7 Darwin/18.2.0 botocore/1.12.123`

Good to go! :)

Comment: Yes - if python was installed using Anaconda, conda install awscli will work.